# Changing an element with js toggle

Tags: javascript

I made a function, so when you click on a link 'Play', div with black background changes to iframe video. It seems to be working fine. Problem is, that I want to add multiple play links with multiple videos. I don't know how to do it, so when you click on second play link, video changes from first video to second in the same place.

my code:

```
<script>
     var toggle = function() {
     var mydiv = document.getElementById('videoholder');document.getElementById("frame").src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YuOBzWF0Aws";
     if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === '')
     mydiv.style.display = 'none';
     else
     mydiv.style.display = 'block' 
     }
</script>


    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle();">PLAY</a><br>
    <div style="width:560px; height:315px; background-color:#111111;">
     <div id="videoholder" style="display:none;">
      <iframe id="frame" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
<script>
    function toggle(url) {
         var mydiv = document.getElementById('videoholder');
         document.getElementById("frame").src = url;
         if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === '') {
             mydiv.style.display = 'none';
         } else {
             mydiv.style.display = 'block'
         }
     }
</script>


<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle('http://www.youtube.com/embed/YuOBzWF0Aws');">PLAY 1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle('http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ');">PLAY 2</a><br>
<div style="width:560px; height:315px; background-color:#111111;">
 <div id="videoholder" style="display:none;">
  <iframe id="frame" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `document.getElementById('frame').src='http://linktonewvideo.com';`

Hope this helps!